# Swift 3 JSON parsing google finance format in array

Tags: json, swift3

I am getting a json file from Google finance that looks like the following

```
[
{
"id": "22144"
,"t" : "AAPL"
,"e" : "NASDAQ"
,"l" : "111.77"
,"l_fix" : "111.77"
,"l_cur" : "111.77"
//and more lines in the same format
}
]
```

However, it looks to be in a different format than expected. If I use the following code

```
if let JSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject {
print("all good")
} else {
print("nope")
}
```

However, it never goes to the all good section. I've tried a number of different approaches on a similar theme with different options, but it does not work.

Is this because of the format of the json, and is there anything I can do to interpret it correctly?

Comment: Cast the deserialization to the more specific type  `[[String:Any]]` or maybe even `[[String:String]]`, an array `[]` of dictionaries `{}`.

Comment: Use of `do/catch` instead of your `if let` and add `print("JSON parsing failed: \(error)")` inside the `catch` block so you know why it failed.